Construction of a Finite State Automaton given a grammar
I have been studying formal language and automata theory from Mathematical Methods in Linguistics (Partee et al.). Specifically, I have been learning about finite state automata, formal languages, and type 3 grammars. In chapter 17, I have encountered the following exercise:

(a) Construct a state diagram for an automaton which accepts the terminal language of the following grammar. (The input alphabet is {a, b, c}; it does not include S or C.)
S -> SS
S -> aCa
S -> bCb
S -> aa
S -> bb
C -> Cc
C -> c


(b) Draw a diagram for an automaton whose language is that of part (a) plus the empty string.

As I have understood it, the grammar in (a) generates a regular language described by (ac*a|bc*b)+, while (b) asks for an automaton that generates (ac*a|bc*b)*.
My response to question (a) was this.
My response to question (b) was this.
The solutions given on the textbook are these.
As you can see, the textbook solution to (a) contains two final states, while mine contains only one. I believe that both solutions are correct, but do let me know if I am missing something. My main issue, however, concerns question (b). In my solution, I have simply made the initial state final; this works because it generates the same language as (a), but now it also includes the empty string, without interfering with any other process. The solution given in the book, however, seems to generate ((a|b)c*)+, which is not at all what I expected.
Is the textbook solution to (b) a mistake, or am I missing something?

Your solution for (a) is indeed correct - states $S_2$ and $S_4$ in textbook solution are indistinguishable, so can be merged. Textbook solution for (b) is very strange - for example, it accepts string a, which should be rejected. It recognizes language ((ac*a)|(bc*b))*(a|b)c*.
